# Showing <p:panel> using <p:commandButton>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How do you display  using ? is it possible?

here is my sample code. this aint working.

```
<h:form>

        <p:panel header="Panel 1" widgetVar="panel1" id="a" >
            <p:commandButton onclick="panel2.show()" value="Show Panel"/>
        </p:panel>

        <p:panel header="Panel 2" widgetVar="panel2" id="b" visible="false">
            <p:outputLabel value="asdasdasdasdsad" />
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can put something like this at onclick action:

```
    <p:panel header="Panel 1" widgetVar="panel1" id="a" >
                <p:commandButton onclick="document.getElementById("b").visble=true" value="Show Panel"/>
            </p:panel>

    <p:panel header="Panel 2" widgetVar="panel2" id="b" visible="false">
            <p:outputLabel value="asdasdasdasdsad" />
        </p:panel>
```

so by defect visible = false and onclick changes to true.

Answer (score 0):

solved!

adding toggleable="true" closable="true" and updating the panel (update="b") in the p:commandButton

```
<p:panel header="Panel 1" widgetVar="panel1" id="a" >
            <p:commandButton value="Show Panel" update="b" widgetVar="btn" onclick="panel2.show()" 
                             >

            </p:commandButton>
        </p:panel>

        <p:panel header="Panel 2" widgetVar="panel2" id="b" toggleable="true" closable="true" visible="false">
                    <p:outputLabel value="asdasdasdasdsad" />
        </p:panel>
```

Comment: Please elaborate the cause and solution in words as well instead of making it an unhelpful Search&Find game.